# PHP Form is not Submitting Images into MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I have a PHP form that has five inputs for the user to upload five images. The user must at least select one image, and it must be in the first input, in order for the form to submit. The form will properly submit all information into the MySQL Table, except for the images themselves. For example, I submitted an image, and the image column shows [BLOB - 14 B], when I believe it should be at least 300 KB. My theory is that the images are being compressed into some other format when they are submitted into the MySQL table.

Here is my full PHP page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

  <html>
  <head><title>File Upload To Database</title></head>
  <body>
  <h2>Please Choose a File and click Submit</h2>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="99999999" />
  <div><input name="userfile[]" type="file" /></div>
    <div><input name="userfile[]" type="file" /></div>
      <div><input name="userfile[]" type="file" /></div>
        <div><input name="userfile[]" type="file" /></div>
          <div><input name="userfile[]" type="file" /></div>
  <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
  </form>

</body></html>

<?php
/*** check if a file was submitted ***/
if(!isset($_FILES['userfile']))
    {
    echo '<p>Please upload a display picture.</p>';
    }
else
    {
    try    {
        upload();
        /*** give praise and thanks to the php gods ***/
        echo '<p>Thank you for submitting</p>';
        }
    catch(Exception $e)
        {
        echo '<h4>'.$e->getMessage().'</h4>';
        }
    }

/*
 * Check the file is of an allowed type
 * Check if the uploaded file is no bigger thant the maximum allowed size
 * connect to the database
 * Insert the data
 */

/**
 *
 * the upload function
 * 
 * @access public
 *
 * @return void
 *
 */
function upload(){

$maxsize = 99999999;
$columnNames = '';
$columnValues = '';
$paramsToBeBound = array();

echo '<pre>' . print_r($_FILES, TRUE) . '</pre>';

/*** check if a file was uploaded ***/
for($i = 0; ($i < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) && $i < 5); $i++) {
    if($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i] != '') { // check if file has been set to upload
        if($_FILES['userfile']['error'][$i] == 0 && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i]) && getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i]) != false) {
            /***  get the image info. ***/
            $size = getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i]);
            /*** assign our variables ***/
            $type = $size['mime'];
            $imgfp = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i], 'rb');
            $size = $size[3];
            $name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];


             /***  check the file is less than the maximum file size ***/
            if($_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i] < $maxsize)
                {
                    if($i > 0) {
                        $columnNames .= ', image_type' . $i . ', image' . $i . ', image_size' . $i . ', image_name' .$i;
                        $columnValues .= ', ?, ?, ?, ?';
                    } else {
                        $columnNames .= 'image_type, image, image_size, image_name';
                        $columnValues .= '?, ?, ?, ?';
                    }

                    $paramsToBeBound[] = $type;
                    $paramsToBeBound[] = $imgfp;
                    $paramsToBeBound[] = $size;
                    $paramsToBeBound[] = $name;
                } else
                    throw new Exception("File Size Error"); //throw an exception is image is not of type
            }
        else
            {
            // if the file is not less than the maximum allowed, print an error
            throw new Exception("Unsupported Image Format of image!");
            }
        }
    }
    if(count($paramsToBeBound) > 0) {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=dsa.com;dbname=s_gbm", 'kss', 'Kisr'); 

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO testblob (' . $columnNames . ') VALUES (' . $columnValues . ')');

        $i = 0;
        foreach($paramsToBeBound as &$param) {
            $i++;
            if($i == 2 || $i - floor($i / 4) == 2) {
                $stmt->bindParam($i, $param, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
            } else {
                $stmt->bindParam($i, $param);
            }
        }

        $stmt->execute();
    }
}


?>
```

Here is the code I used in PHP MyAdmin SQL to create the MySQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE testblob ( image_id tinyint(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, image_type varchar(25) NOT NULL, image longblob NOT NULL, image_size varchar(25) NOT NULL, image_name varchar(50) NOT NULL, image_type1 varchar(25) NOT NULL, image1 longblob NOT NULL, image_size1 varchar(25) NOT NULL, image_name1 varchar(50) NOT NULL, image_type2 varchar(25) NOT NULL, image2 longblob NOT NULL, image_size2 varchar(25) NOT NULL, image_name2 varchar(50) NOT NULL, image_type3 varchar(25) NOT NULL, image3 longblob NOT NULL, image_size3 varchar(25) NOT NULL, image_name3 varchar(50) NOT NULL, image_type4 varchar(25) NOT NULL, image4 longblob NOT NULL, image_size4 varchar(25) NOT NULL, image_name4 varchar(50) NOT NULL, image_ctgy varchar(25) NOT NULL, KEY image_id (image_id) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Thank you for any help. I appreciate all help given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I suggest not storing images in MySQL unless you absolutely have to.

Do you absolutely have to?  Yes?  That's unfortunate.  This should help though…

```
$imgfp = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i], 'rb');
$imageData = fread($imgfp, filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i]));
$imageData = addslashes($imageData);
fclose($imgfp);
…
…
$paramsToBeBound[] = $imageData;
```

Comment: Another approach Is store image as base64 - thats because you don't need to reprocess the content to show like `background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG etc...);` or img tag

Comment: @RagenDazs That's an interesting approach indeed! Thanks for that nugget.

Answer (score 2):

you should never store any media type in a MySQL database, what you should do is store the media file be it picture or video on a local hard drive, then have MySQL store a file that will call that media type when needed. i hoped this helped (=

Comment: While a good comment, just telling someone not to do something isn't a particularly great answer.  The OP may be in some situation where no alternative is available (although I would really hope this isn't the case, for the OP's sake)

Comment: The OP can, for example, require replication or use some business rule inside MySQL.

Comment: sorry i was just trying to help out, storing video or picture in a MySQL database will in most cases cause the database to overload, next time i answer a question ill try to put in more detail